# Disk2VHD reboots without warning

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, disk2vhd

I  recently tried cloning (p2v) my old desktop machine using SysInternals Disk2VHD tool (link text)

But the app doesn't get past the 'Snapshotting volumes' message on Disk2VHD without my machine rebooting itself without warning.

The desktop machine is running XP latest service pack and hotfixes.

Does anyone have any advice on how do troubleshoot this issue ?

Comment: Which version of Disk2VHD do you use? There is a 1.3 recently out.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen systems react poorly to snapshots if there was a filesystem or hardware problem.

Does the reboot happen earlier or later in the 'Snapshotting volumes' stage?  If not, it could be a problem with a particular part of the filesystem or disk; have you tried running `chkdsk` or querying the disk for SMART information to see if it's failing?

You probably put a bullet in that box two years ago, but just in case you still have the drive laying around, I'd be curious to see if your old system can be revived and virtualized.